# Use 'virtual' in an array of objects (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, schema, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas as the following:

```
const castListSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  roleInVideo: String
});

const videoSchema = new Schame({
  castList: { type: [castListSchema], default: [] }
});
```

I want to get data by the following structure:

```
castList: [
  {
    details: { ... },
    roleInVideo: 'director'

  },
  ...
]
```

I want to use `virtual` not `aggregate` and etc...

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the virtual function inside the array of objects.

Use the following code to use the virtual function for the array of objects.

```
videoSchema.virtual("castList.castData", {
  ref: "new_assets",
  localField: "castList.castListSchema",
  foreignField: "_id",
  justOne: true
});
```

In populate also use this "castList.castData" as key to retrieve the data.

Comment: With the explanation that 'ref' should refer to our collection(e.g. `Cast` in this example),
@kartik-goyal thanks

Comment: It does not work for me